# SaaS approach to App_GlobalResources

Tags: localization, globalization, saas, app-globalresources

We are building an app where *multiple* websites are powered by a *single* site on IIS

We have a web-based tool where webmaster can edit the "resx" files, like:
/App_GlobalResources/es/Backend.es.resx

However there is two problems with this:

1. changing these files effects *all* sites.
2. It also causes the entire IIS site to restart.

Is there another approach to this?
I think storing the strings in a DB may be a bad idea as it will cause hundreds of SQL lookups per page.

Comment: 1. Editing the "satellite" .resx files shouldn't force a restart. 2. Use a database if you like, just incorporate caching.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database driven resource provider that supports caching. And you are in luck because [someone else](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/) already [done it](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you provide an interface to edit the resx files? If so, cache them in the Application scope and expire the cache when they are updated. Then, store them in the database. This way, you'll have both speed and flexibility.
Just because the data is in database, doesn't mean it'll be slow. Cache is the solution. Of course, the first lookup will be slow, but subsequent lookups will be as fast as you can get.